# react-native module not found error even though the file is present

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native and I'm facing module not found error. my folder structure is as follows

```
app/
    assets/
    components/
        home.js
        header.js
App.js
```

**header.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

export default class Header extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
    <Text>
        this is header
    </Text>
    );
   }
}
```

**home.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import Header from 'header';

export default class Home extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Header/>
            <Text>
                this is homepage
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
   }
}
```

**App.js**
header.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import Home from './app/components/home';

export default class App extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Home/>
        </View>
    );
   }
}
```

I have been looking for an answer for hours but no solution so far. if I remove the import for Header class in home.js it works.

Comment: Hello! Have you tried importing header as such? **import Header from './header'** instead of **import Header from 'header'**:D

Comment: @seu wow! Thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import header as

```
import Header from './header'
```

instead of

```
import Header from 'header'
```